# Calculate the total from 2 tables - Powerbi

Tags: powerbi, dax

So, I have two tables I need to combine without merging as I was told merging the tables does not auto update when posted so had to separate my tables. So, I have Fioptics and legacy tables where I pull RecordID, JobTypeID and CustTypeID individually below is how my code looks

```
legacy res install =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( LEGACY[RecordID] ),
    FILTER (
        LEGACY,
        LEGACY[JobTypeID] = 1
            && LEGACY[CustTypeID] = 1
            && LEGACY[prod_grouping] = "legacy"
    )
)
```

and

```
fioptics res install =
CALCULATE (
    COUNT ( FIOPTIC[RecordID] ),
    FILTER (
        FIOPTIC,
        FIOPTIC[JobTypeID] = 1
            && FIOPTIC[CustTypeID] = 1
            && FIOPTIC[prod_grouping] = "fioptics"
    )
)
```

how do I go about using a dax function to pull from both RecordID's, JobTypeID and CustTypeID and filter from my FIOPTICS AND LEGACY tables at the same time? It might be a simple answer but having a brain fart maybe overlooking a simple solution to this problem.

Comment: "merging the tables does not auto update when posted" - never heard that, any reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can combine those columns in a **calculated table**

```
Combined = 
UNION(
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        LEGACY,
        "RecordID", LEGACY[RecordID],
        "JobTypeID", LEGACY[JobTypeID],
        "CustTypeID", LEGACY[CustTypeID]
    ),
    SELECTCOLUMNS(
        FIOPTICS,
        "RecordID", FIOPTICS[RecordID],
        "JobTypeID", FIOPTICS[JobTypeID],
        "CustTypeID", FIOPTICS[CustTypeID]
    )
)
```

And of cause you can filter the combined table in your report to your needs.